# How to change the default amount of increase indentation in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

The default amount of "increase indentation" whenever I highlight a few lines to indent is too big for me. I would like to halve that amount.

How do you set this? I don't want to set this every time I indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the default template - Normal.dotm

First open a new document and open the **Paragraph** to set the indentation you like.

[image: Paragraph]

[image: Identation]

Change the left indentation to 2"

Now save the document as Word Template (click the Office button | Save As | Word Template). Browse to:

```
C:\Users\answertips\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
```

and name the document `Normal_New.dotm`.

[image]

Close Word. In Windows Explorer go to:

```
C:\Users\answertips\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
```

and rename `Normal.dotm` to `Normal_Old.dotm` (this is to keep a copy of your original template file). Select `Normal_New.dotm` and rename it to `Normal.dotm`.

Now, the default indent should be 2".

Comment: Does it answers your question?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to `Paragraph` -> `Tabs` and set `Default tab stops` as you want.

Here are the pictures of these menus.

1.
[image: Paragraph]

2.
[image: Tabs]

3.
[image: Default tab stops]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this is the same issue I was just trying to figure out. Here is the solution I found:

In the "Paragraph" window (as seen above), click on the "Tabs..." button.

When the "Tabs" dialog opens, on the top-right is a box titled "Default tab stops:"

Set that to the value you want, and (after clicking "OK" and closing the dialogs) when you click the "Increase Indent" button, it will jump to where you set it.

Now you can save those settings to a default template as you want and you'll be ready to rock! (Hope that helps)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a setting in the style you are using - check that first.

Home Ribbon > Change Styles > Paragraph Spacing > Custom

Fool around in there and see how you go

Comment: It's not a permanent setting. It's only for the text you're working on.